# Linux-Ubuntu: how can i install the python module autopy?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I am running an ubuntu machine. Does anyone know how to install the module autopy?
here is the link:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/autopy/

Comment: Please edit your question to show what command(s) you have tried and what error message(s) you are getting to make it easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 3):

Worked for me

sudo pip install autopy

Comment: src/keypress.c:10:35: fatal error: X11/extensions/XTest.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden

compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: another way is download the autopy-0.51.tar.gz and then python setup.py install

Comment: python setup.py install did't worked!!