# How to install module autopy in python on linux?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, centos, vmware

I wanna install module Autop 0.51 on Linux.  What should i do.?

```
python Setup.py install
```

It show error please help me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zKEY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjcnz.jpg

Comment: Not really a programming question, is it? Answered here, but very off topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17814444/linux-ubuntu-how-can-i-install-the-python-module-autopy

Comment: try `pip install autopy`

Comment: also provide error log

Comment: also... try `python Setup.py` instead of `python Setup.py install`

Comment: what you tried? what error?

Comment: i try pip install autopy it error

Answer (score 0):

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

The above error occurs because you don't have the python-dev headers installed

Do a `yum search python | grep -i devel` and then install the appropriate package for eg:

`yum  install python-devel.x86_64`

Comment: yum search python | grep -i devel

Comment: yum install python-devel.x86_64

Comment: Yes. Try installing it and that should fix it.

Comment: Try `yum clean all` and then try again